# How to retrieve Owner Description from OwnerID in Universal Search

Tags: acumatica

I modified LeadExtension to add the ownerid so salespeople knows who's leads are theirs during universal search of email address.  However I could only get it to report the ID which is a number and not the description.  Is there an easy way to modify the following to report the actual name of the employee instead of ID number using typeof(Contact.ownerID):

```
 //modify leads search to report ownerid
    public class LeadExtension : PXCacheExtension<Contact>
    {
        [PXRemoveBaseAttribute(typeof(PXSearchableAttribute))]
        [PXMergeAttributes(Method = MergeMethod.Append)]
        [PXSearchable(SearchCategory.CR, "{0} {1}", new Type[] { typeof(Contact.contactType), typeof(Contact.displayName) },
                    new Type[] { typeof(Contact.eMail), typeof(Contact.phone1), typeof(Contact.phone2), typeof(Contact.phone3), typeof(Contact.webSite) },
                     WhereConstraint = typeof(Where<Current<Contact.contactType>, NotEqual<ContactTypesAttribute.bAccountProperty>, And<Current<Contact.contactType>, NotEqual<ContactTypesAttribute.employee>>>),
                     Line1Format = "{0}{1}{2}{3}", Line1Fields = new Type[] { typeof(Contact.salutation), typeof(Contact.phone1), typeof(Contact.eMail), typeof(Contact.ownerID) },
                     Line2Format = "{1}{2}{3}", Line2Fields = new Type[] { typeof(Contact.defAddressID), typeof(Address.displayName), typeof(Address.city), typeof(Address.state), typeof(Address.countryID) }
                    )]
        public Guid? NoteID { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show the actual name of the employee instead of ID number, you should also include `TM.PXOwnerSelectorAttribute.EPEmployee.acctName` field. Since associated Employee is accessible only though the OwnerID field, **Contact.ownerID must also present in the Line1Fields array prior to** `TM.PXOwnerSelectorAttribute.EPEmployee.acctName` field. And don't forget to change the Line1Format property to `{0}{1}{2}{4}`, otherwise it will still show ID number.

Below is the final extension code for your reference:

```
public class LeadExtension : PXCacheExtension<Contact>
{
    [PXRemoveBaseAttribute(typeof(PXSearchableAttribute))]
    [PXMergeAttributes(Method = MergeMethod.Append)]
    [PXSearchable(SearchCategory.CR, "{0} {1}", new Type[] { typeof(Contact.contactType), typeof(Contact.displayName) },
         new Type[] { typeof(Contact.eMail), typeof(Contact.phone1), typeof(Contact.phone2), typeof(Contact.phone3), typeof(Contact.webSite) },
         WhereConstraint = typeof(Where<Current<Contact.contactType>, NotEqual<ContactTypesAttribute.bAccountProperty>, And<Current<Contact.contactType>, NotEqual<ContactTypesAttribute.employee>>>),
         Line1Format = "{0}{1}{2}{4}", 
         Line1Fields = new Type[] { typeof(Contact.salutation), typeof(Contact.phone1), typeof(Contact.eMail),
                                    typeof(Contact.ownerID), typeof(TM.PXOwnerSelectorAttribute.EPEmployee.acctName) },
         Line2Format = "{1}{2}{3}", 
         Line2Fields = new Type[] { typeof(Contact.defAddressID), typeof(Address.displayName), typeof(Address.city), typeof(Address.state), typeof(Address.countryID) }
    )]
    public Guid? NoteID { get; set; }
}
```